# Body design for 10 Senses

Tags: creature-design

A creature has 10 senses other than sight,smell,taste,touch,hearing*
*subject to addition very soon*

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  You question is unclear.  What do you mean by "10 dimensional?"  What are "psychological abilities?"  One way of looking at multiple dimensions is to consider the 4th dimension to be time.  Is your creature able to "see" through time?  What are the 10 dimensions in your universe?  Please edit your question with the clarifications.  Thanks!

Comment: 1) We do not "cope" with 3D, we use 3D because that is how we see the world. To your creature it should be the same. 2) How can 3D creatures (we) even try to understand what would a 10D creature's abilities be?

Comment: There must be some adaptations for us to use our 3D depth perception.The same what must the adaptations of my creature have to use its 10D depth perception.

Comment: A by psychological abilities I mean adaptations to its brain to use it.

Comment: and yes it should be able to see through time

Comment: I believe there's a misunderstanding.  What allows us to see 3D in a world that includes 2D and 1D objects is binocular vision - two eyes and a brain that can process the two 2D images and create a 3D composite.  You can't just add a third eye to see "time."  From our perspective, the ability to see through time (4D vision) makes your creature god-like.  We might be able to tackle that, but even if you tell us what the other 6 dimensions are (you must), I'm not sure we can help you beyond "god-like."  How would an amoeba conceptualize a human being?

Comment: I have decided to change the question up a bit, I will change it shortly.

Comment: could someone please take this post down

Comment: like remove it from the page

Comment: Kat KK i am sorry that your answer went to waste

Comment: but i still appreciate the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to perceive the concept of 10th dimension from the viewpoint of a three dimensional being like us. Even if we still count time in, we are still three-dimensional beings. What's tricky about understanding a 10-dimensional condition is that having multi-dimensional perception is not all about your own sense of self. You may have noticed that starting from the 5th dimension, the point of existence has progressed into other worlds,other possibilities, infinite possibilities and so on. At least, this is what we know about different dimensions. May be one character in particular who's highly popular nowadays, being able to perceive 10 dimensions is Dr Strange. He's able to manipulate and see through space-time continuum. He is literally able to see everything possible and what not.

Comment: *"starting from the 5th dimension, the point of existence has progressed into other worlds,other possibilities, infinite possibilities and so on"* [citation needed]